# How to set query execution time out in DBCP?

Tags: java, jdbc, connection-pooling, apache-commons-dbcp

I am using DBCP as connection pool in Hive JDBC.

A particular query got hang for long time due to some tez session issue in hive. JDBC code also got stucked due to this. Is there any way to provide execution query timeout?

I found `setValidationQueryTimeout()` but did not find anything for actual queries.

```
    BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
    ds.setValidationQueryTimeout(timeout);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have not used DBCP but as per [documentation](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/configuration.html) , property , `defaultQueryTimeout`  seems to be the option that you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You must be using the [1.x version](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/dbcp/BasicDataSource.html) of dbcp. It doesn't seem to contain thid `defaultQueryTimeout`

Whereas the [2.x versions](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/api-2.1/org/apache/commons/dbcp2/BasicDataSource.html#getDefaultQueryTimeout--) of dbcp, contain the property.

I think the [configuration doc](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/configuration.html) contains the latest doc info which is confusing.